# Force iCloud to sync from phone reminders

Tags: icloud, reminders

I went from iPhone to Android and now back to iPhone.

iCloud seems to have my old iPhones reminders even though I have iCloud turned on for reminders on new phone. I only know this because I opened iCloud reminders from my PC for the first time in several years and found the problem.

If I turn iCloud off and back on though my phone settings it says it will delete all local reminders and refresh from iCloud which is useless to me.

Is there a way to sync *from* my iPhone up to the cloud so the cloud reflects the current reminders app contents?

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear out iCloud Reminders *first* before you connect your iPhone and synchronize it.

> iCloud seems to have my old iPhones reminders … I opened iCloud reminders from my PC for the first time in several years and found the problem.

Follow these steps to get the reminders on your iPhone to iCloud (assumes you’ve already disabled iCloud sync on your iPhone):

1. Turn or remove iCloud sync on your PC
2. Log into iCloud.com
3. Open Reminders and ensure everything is deleted
4. Enable iCloud sync on your phone.

If you have other devices synchronizing Reminders (like a MacBook or iPad, for example), you need to disable these as well.

Comment: Thanks Allan. I considered that but iCloud is already running on my iPhone and has been for ages. When I go to turn it off and then back on it says it will delete all icloud reminders locally and synch down from the cloud. Which should work BUT I oi not know what it considers to be iCloud stuff locally and considering synch has been on for months maybe it believes the local reminders are icloud ones and will delete them....

Comment: I’m confused…” I went from iPhone to Android and now back to iPhone.” Are you *not* on an iPhone now coming from an Android?

Comment: Please see the update to my response. Yes - iphone then android and now back to iphone.

Comment: Yes…it’s technically a “new” iPhone to you.  I’m treating it as such.  If you think of it as a “new” device, then this will explain why iCloud is doing what it’s doing.  If you want to go the other way, you have to treat iCloud as a new service.  It’s like you had an iPhone and you’re now adding iCloud so it take the info from your phone.

Comment: I've had the phone for 6 months so its not techincally a new phone. I turned on iCloud synch at the start and was never given any indication it was not synching until I actually checked icloud today. Lets not forget that technology should be working for us, not the other way around. There is nothing logical in what it has done but I now need to find a way round this OR be assured it will not delete all my local reminder data. Are you able to help with either of those? Thanks

Comment: The way Apple engineers (putting myself in their shoes) would look at this is you have iCloud and a PC synching.  Then, a never before seen (to iCloud) iPhone shows up.  It’s thinking you want the data from your PC and iCloud on the new (supposedly blank) iPhone, not the other way around.    To get what you want, we have to “trick” iCloud.  Granted, Apple would probbly benefit from having a simple box to say “sync to/from” iCloud and allow you to choose.

Comment: "To get what you want, we have to “trick” iCloud. " 

Ok - so you are saying the following method will definitely NOT clear all data in reminders on my iPhone to reflect what the cloud says?

And that first line should say remove icloud on iPhone right?

Turn or remove iCloud sync on your PC 
Log into iCloud.com
Open Reminders and ensure everything is deleted
Enable iCloud sync on your phone.

Comment: That's correct.  Once iCloud is back to an empty state, when you enable it on your phone it should sync up.  If it tries to sync down it will still give you that error message.  If it does, don't proceed and we'll figure out a different way.